# não consigo adicionar elemento ao DOM através de uma função anônima em JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, função-anônima

Criei uma tabela via javascript ao manipular elementos de um array, quanto à isso esta tudo correto, porém, só consigo adicionar a tabela no DOM por uma função comum ou por uma função anônima do Jquery, mas quando a função anônima é do javascript, ele não consegue adicionar a tabela ao DOM...

feita com função anônima js (não funciona):

```
(function(){
    const alunos = [
        { nome: 'Ana', nota: 9.1 },
        { nome: 'Bianca', nota: 8.4 },
        { nome: 'Carlos', nota: 7.6 },
        { nome: 'Julia', nota: 9.7 }
    ]
    const linhas = alunos.map(aluno => {
        const tdNome = `<td>${aluno.nome}</td>`
        const tdNota = `<td>${aluno.nota}</td>`
        return '<tr>' + tdNome + tdNota + '</tr>'
    })
    const tabela = linhas.reduce((tabela, elemendo) => tabela + elemendo ,'')
    document.getElementById('conteudo').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<table>${tabela}</table>`)
})
```

feita com função comum em js (funciona):

```
 function criarTabela(){
        const alunos = [
            { nome: 'Ana', nota: 9.1 },
            { nome: 'Bianca', nota: 8.4 },
            { nome: 'Carlos', nota: 7.6 },
            { nome: 'Julia', nota: 9.7 }
        ]
        const linhas = alunos.map(aluno => {
            const tdNome = `<td>${aluno.nome}</td>`
            const tdNota = `<td>${aluno.nota}</td>`
            return '<tr>' + tdNome + tdNota + '</tr>'
        })
        const tabela = linhas.reduce((tabela, elemendo) => tabela + elemendo ,'')
         document.getElementById('conteudo').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<table>${tabela}</table>`)</table>`)
    }
    criarTabela()
```

feita com função anônima Jquery (funciona):

```
$(function (){
    const alunos = [
        { nome: 'Ana', nota: 9.1 },       
        { nome: 'Bianca', nota: 8.4 },  
        { nome: 'Carlos', nota: 7.6 },    
        { nome: 'Julia', nota: 9.7 }      
    ]
    const linhas = alunos.map(aluno => {          
        const tdNome = $('<td>').html(aluno.nome)
        const tdNota = $('<td>').html(aluno.nota)
        return $('<tr>').append(tdNome, tdNota) 
    })

    const tabela = $('<table>').append(linhas)
        .css("border", "solid 5px")
    $('#conteudo').append(tabela)
})
```

o html não possui nada de especial, apenas uma div com um ID:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>tabelo feita de um objeto</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/estilo.css'>
    <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
</head>

<body class='conteudo exercicio'>
    <h1>criando tabela</h1>
    <div id='conteudo'></div>
```

Comment: Isso é só um erro de sintaxe. Você está declarando a função mas não está a invocando. Adicione um par de parenteses no fim da declaração, ela deve ficar dessa forma: `(function() { /* ... */ })()`

Comment: isso mesmo, eu estava confundindo a sintaxe do Jquery com a do JS. obrigado!

Comment: Eu acho que a função simplesmente nao esta a ser chamada, use () para a chamar e logo a seguir as Brackets.

Comment: sim, é exatamente isso, confundi a sintaxe do jquery com a do js. obrigado :D